# Memory consumption for ios app

Tags: ios, memory

I am trying to look into memory consumption in apps. So I created a very basic project (with just a single label, image shown) and ran it in a simulator. The memory report graph  shows around 42MB being used. Is this normal for a simple project like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to examine memory used try it on real device not in simulator, and yes usually normal memory consumed in simulator is like this around 42, **check on real device for memory consumption**

Comment: @iOSGeek Got it, testing on a real device shows around 8MB. Thank you.

Comment: Shall I Post this as an Answer ?

Comment: Sure, you may post @iOSGeek

Comment: Thanks I did Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to examine memory used try it on real device not in simulator, and yes usually normal memory consumed in simulator is like this around 42, `check on real device for memory consumption`